# Is it possible to define implicit or explicit conversion between third-party library types?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with Qt as well as other libraries. Qt uses `QString` instead of `std::string`. When I want to use the libraries that are not Qt, the functions request an `std::string`, therefore, every time I have to call the non-Qt library I have to use the conversion `QString::toUtf8().constData()`. Is there a way that I can write an explicit or implicit conversion (I do not know which one should it be) that lets me use `QString` in the place of `std::string`?

An example would be something like

```
void func(std::string in)
{
    std::cout<<in<<std::endl;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
QString s("this is the message");
func(s);
```

instead of

```
QString s("this is the message");
func(s.toUtf8().constData());
```

I cannot provide any example of what I have tried to do because I have only found [conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for classes that are custom made.

Thank you.

Comment: QString has a `toStdString` member

Comment: That, as far as I know, do not solve my question. However, it does simplify a bit the `QString::toUtf8().constData()` part. Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is: No, conversions are members of the class, and you can only get one user-defined conversion per expression

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a long answer providing a workaround? (just in case) :)

Comment: Wrap `QString` and `std::string` in custom classes that define the desired conversion operators between them